# Mysql Join: How to use the same result set for multiple tables

Tags: mysql, join, resultset

I was practicing mysql queries in http://sqlzoo.net/wiki/Main_Page and came across this particular query regarding joins. 
Question :List the film title and the leading actor for all of the films 'Julie Andrews' played in.
Table structure :

```
movie   : id,title,yr,director,budget,gross -------
actor   :id,name ----------
casting :movieid,actorid,ord
```

Hint : Leading actors are actors having ord as 1 in casting table
My answer up till now : I can get the movie id and actor id for all of the films 'Julie Andrews' played in. But using that result set , i do not know how to get title and name which are in different tables.

My Query so far :

```
select c1.actorid,c1.movieid 
from casting c1 
where c1.movieid in 
(
   select movieid from casting 
   join  actor on (id=actorid and name='Julie Andrews')
) and c1.ord=1
```

Comment: You don't need a select statement inside the other. You just want one statement that has a join.

Comment: HI,Thanks for ur reply. This query is working correctly : select m.title,a.name from actor a join casting c on (a.id=c.actorid and c.ord=1) join movie m on ( m.id=c.movieid) and m.id in (select movieid from casting join  actor on (id=actorid and name='Julie Andrews') )

Answer (score 0):

As a learning exercise, you should to break the query down into steps.

**Step 1.  List film titles**

```
SELECT movie.title AS title
FROM movie
```

**Step 2.  List the films that Julie Andrews starred in:**

```
SELECT movie.title AS title
FROM movie
JOIN casting
  ON movie.id = casting.movieid
JOIN actor
  ON casting.actorid = actor.id
WHERE actor.name = 'Julie Andrews'
```

**Step 3.  Lead actors.  This is where you can begin to differ your solution depending how your problem solving works.**

If you want to know just lead actors names.  Your query would look something like this:

```
SELECT actor.name as Name 
FROM casting
JOIN actor
  ON actor.id = casting.actorid
WHERE casting.ord =1
```

However, if you try this:

```
SELECT movie.title AS title
FROM movie
JOIN casting
  ON movie.id = casting.movieid
JOIN actor
  ON casting.actorid = actor.id
WHERE actor.name = 'Julie Andrews'
  AND casting.ord =1;
```

You are merely finding where Julie Andrews is the lead actor.

Instead you need to join back to the actors table (I will add some table aliases that help explain the purpose of the tables being joined)

```
SELECT movie.title AS title, LeadActor.name AS LeadActorName
FROM movie
JOIN casting AS JulieCastings
  ON movie.id = JulieCastings.movieid
JOIN actor AS JulieAndrews
  ON JulieCastings.actorid = JulieAndrews.id
JOIN casting AS LeadActorCastings
  ON LeadActorCastings.movieid = movie.id
JOIN actor AS LeadActor
  ON LeadActor.id = LeadActorCastings.actorid
WHERE JulieAndrews.name = 'Julie Andrews'
  AND LeadActor.ord =1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should use join instead:

```
      select c1.actorid, c1.movieid 
        join casting c2 on c2.movieid = c1.movieid
        join  actor a on a.id=c2.actorid
      from casting c1 
        where c1.ord=1 and
              a.name='Julie Andrews'
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys.
I have solved it with the following query :
select m.title,a.name from actor a join casting c on (a.id=c.actorid and c.ord=1) join movie m on ( m.id=c.movieid) and m.id in (select movieid from casting join actor on (id=actorid and name='Julie Andrews') )

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread, but for anyone still looking for help like me, I worked off of Shankar's a bit and used this. Hope this helps.

```
SELECT title, name 
FROM movie JOIN casting ON (movie.id = casting.movieid) 
           JOIN actor ON (actor.id = casting.actorid)
WHERE movieid IN (SELECT movieid 
                  FROM casting JOIN actor ON (actor.id = casting.actorid)
                  WHERE name = 'Julie Andrews') 
                  AND ord = 1
```